# How to match 3D model perspective to an image

Tags: c++, model, 3d, match, perspective

I have a 3D model and an image. I can manually adjust the perspective of the model using gluPerspective. I'm looking for a way to use corresponding points (probably at least 6 or 7) on the model and image to determine how to adjust the modelview matrix and projection matrix so that the model matches the image.

I've searched Google (mostly OpenCV), but everything seems to be about aligning two images or creating a model from an image. I already have the model. I just need to know what scale, rotation, camera position, and FOV is needed to make the model look like the image.

Ideally I was hoping to find a function that I could just input an array of image points and an array of model points and get back some transformation matrix. I could then somehow apply this matrix to the the model matrix and magically match the model to the image.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No real good way to do this, I'm afraid. What you have is a 3D fiducial marker, and are trying to get the position from this fiducial marker...kindof. That's where I would start looking, but if your trying to find something that works out of the box and are not looking to get this done for a PHD thesis, your probably SOL.

Comment: You do know that your problem is underdetermined when you want to find both FOV AND scale? Or that camera position and model orientation are "equivalent"?

Comment: Thanks both of you. I figured I was probably SOL finding a simple way to do this. Good point Andre, just camera position and viewing frustum needed.

Comment: I know this post it's a bit outdated, but I would like to know if now is it possible to find something as said by @user3120008. I have the 3D model, i have the image, then select the points of 3D model, the points of images, and boom, I obtain the transformation matrix, that give me the possibility to project the model on the image.